# GeoServer WMS layers not working on Azure app service

Tags: geoserver, azure

Tl;dr I'm hosting GeoServer (2.15.0) in an Azure app service Java container with Tomcat. I can access the admin panel, but none of the layer previews work, nor can I fetch them over WMS service. They just timeout after a while.

In July a couple of colleagues used GeoServer and leaflet.js to show some map data in a web app. Fast forward to today, they've both quit the company and I took over the project. Nothing was changed on the app service or the GeoServer since then (we have 2 separate instances of GeoServer) but they've both stopped working.
I've tried reinstalling GeoServer on one of the instances, changed different settings in Azure portal (Java & Tomcat versions), created a new app service and installed a fresh copy of GeoServer to no avail.
I've contacted my former colleagues and they say the last time it was a simple thing of unpacking the zip and it all worked (another colleague confirms it).

Before I try other options (using a virtual machine), has anyone encountered similar problems? Is there some trick to hosting GeoServer in an Azure app service?

Comment: 2.15 is unsupported, so maybe start a newer version? After that, can you post what is in the logs? On the GEOS Jira ticket that you just raised would be ideal: https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/browse/GEOS-9549

Comment: I have customers who run GeoServer on Azure with no issues

Comment: In the end I gave up on hosting GeoServer in an app service. There is a GeoServer resource that can be created (https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en/marketplace/apps/apps-4-rent.geoserver-windows-server-2016?tab=Overview). It's just a virtual machine that comes with a preinstalled GeoServer.

Comment: I have the same issue - Windows app (tomact 8 java 8). Layer previews just time out. Seems like there is an incompatibility with azure Window web app and the current version of geoserver.

Comment: did you set the Proxy URL? Layer preview may well be using localhost if you did not?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem and I solved it switching from Window app to a Linux stack (tomcat 8 and java 8). In the folder /wwwroot I had deployed the geoserver folder and not the war package.